# Загрузка файла с помощью nemmo/yii2-attachments в Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii

Установил расширение nemmo/yii2-attachments, но там нет инструкции как загружать файлы. Может кто нибудь приведет пример

Answer (score 0):

Там есть инструкция.

Контроллер:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new MyModel();

    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Всё ок!');
        return $this->redirect(['index']); // Нужный url для переадресации
    }

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Вьюшка:

```
<?php \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
    <?php echo \nemmo\attachments\components\AttachmentsInput::widget([
        'id' => 'file-input', // Optional
        'model' => $model,
        'options' => [ // Options of the Kartik's FileInput widget
            'multiple' => true, // If you want to allow multiple upload, default to false
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [ // Plugin options of the Kartik's FileInput widget 
            'maxFileCount' => 10 // Client max files
        ]
    ]) ?>
<?php \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end() ?>
```